# swimlane/ngx-datatable having performance issue with Angular 13

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable, angular13

I Updated my app to from angular 12 to 13,  during the upgrade process I added below overrides in package.json as 6.6.7 version of rxjs was throwing error in Angular 13

```
"overrides": {
    "rxjs": "7.4.0"
  },
```

Was using rxjs - 6 before,

After The upgrade i am experiencing lag in datatable where there is large amount of data, which was fine when running it in Angular 12

Comment: Can you please provide a code block that shows how you use related package and how you use rxjs operators in your code?

Comment: Did not used rxjs directly it is used by swimlane/ngx-datatable interally